# Remove border from a-Tag if the link is an image

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS code:

```
HTML:
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>

CSS:
a:hover {
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

The issue is, that the a-Tag should add the border when hovering only if the enclosed link is NOT an image.

The border is not on the image, it is on the a-Tag...How can I solve this?

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Add a class to the links that have an image in them. There is no selector that can look if an anchor tag has an image and than apply something to that anchor tag.

Comment: For hovering text links there is the CSS property
`text-decoration: underline;`
Use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a img, a img:hover { border:none; }
```

if you have only one a-tag that has an image, you can use an id

```
#myImageATag, #myImageATag:hover{
   border:none;
}
<a id="myImageATag"></a>
```

If you wan to apply to many others, you can use a `class`

```
.linksWithImages, .linksWithImages:hover{
        border:none;
}
```

I don't know if you can use Jquery but this is a solution to check if there is an image then remove the border. How to check if the a tag has an image below in jQuery

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('img').length === 0) {
        $(this).css("border", "none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS cannot do this , but Jquery can easily help you :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").parent("a").css( "border-bottom" , "none" );
});
```

test it here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGZbVj

Answer (score 0):

use following CSS for anchor image link:

```
a img { border: none; }

a:hover img { border: none; }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please remember to use the code block when adding code snippet to your answers.